# Book with a man on an alien planet who cooked biscuits for the aliens in a copper kettle

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read a sci-fi book back in high school, around 88-91. It involved a frontier man on alien planet and fuzzy aliens who liked biscuits cooked in a brass or copper kettle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems thin for the plot of a novel; was it perhaps a shorter work in a collection?  Why did the aliens like the biscuits?  What did the frontier man get out of it?

Comment: Fuzzy aliens makes me think of *[Little Fuzzy](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/18137/pg18137-images.html)*, but no mention of copper kettles.

Comment: Fuzzies needed a trace element that was in some kind of standard "trade candy" that the humans brought with  them.  Most types of intelligent beings could eat it and most of them found it tasted good.  Fuzzies loved it because they had a special taste for that trace element - it was needed for reproduction.  The trace element was in the stuff because the factory it was made in had pots made of the metal.  I keep wanting to say it was titanium, not copper.

Comment: @JRE It was in fact titanium, or trace compounds thereof ("hokfusine").

Answer (score 16):

It's not an exact match, since the metal involved is titanium, not brass or copper, and the "frontier man" isn't the one who does the cooking, but this is a partial match for [*Fuzzy Sapiens*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?186702), which was reprinted by Ace Books several times through the 1980s.

The titular Fuzzies are, well, fuzzy; see the cover image below:

[image: Cover of "Fuzzy Sapiens"]

The "frontier man" would be Jack Holloway, who was the first person to discover the Fuzzies, and who became their first champion.  Jack is an older man who had previously lived a mostly solitary life as a prospector and sunstone digger.  (This is mostly covered in the previous book *Little Fuzzy*.)  In this story Jack is now the "Commissioner of Native Affairs" and his quiet country life is being invaded by his responsibilities.

In this story an investigation is made of why the Fuzzies seem to love Extee-Three ("Estee-fee" in Fuzzy dialect), short for "Emergency Field Ration, Extraterrestrial Service type Three," which in the classic tradition of military ready rations everywhere is largely considered inedible.  They determine that the reason is that Extee-three contains noticeable trace amounts of titanium, and that the Fuzzy diet is deficient in titanium.  (In fact the reason for the Fuzzy population's migration, which kicked off the events of the first book, was to follow their traditional source of dietary titanium, the land-prawn or "zatku.")

The person with the titanium kettle who first made "hokfusine" for the Fuzzies was Victor Grego, the Charterless Zarathustra Company's CEO, who adopts a Fuzzy he names Diamond.

> "Hoenveld found what was different about it." The explanation was rather complicated; she had been exposed to, rather than studied, chemistry. She got the general idea; **the Extee-Three the Fuzzies liked had been cooked in titanium.**
>
> "**That's what this stew pan is**; part of a camp cooking kit I brought here from Terra." He gave the white mess in the pan a final stir and lifted it from the stove, burning his finger and swearing; just like a man in a kitchen. "Now, as soon as this slop's cool..."
>
> Diamond smelled it, and wanted to try it right away. He had to wait, though, until it was cool. Then they carried the pan, it had a treacherous-looking folding handle, out to the Fuzzy-room, and Mr. Grego spooned some onto Diamond’s plate, and Diamond took his little spoon and tasted, cautiously. Then he began shoveling it into his mouth ravenously.